# Why is non binary number evaluated as binary

Tags: javascript

How come the following

```
0xf & 1000
```

evaluates to 8 ?
I'm specifying `1000` as non binary, does the operator `&` perform the conversion to binary? This also evaluates to 8

```
0xf & 0b1000
```

but the second number is explicitly defined as binary

Comment: 1000 == 0b1111101000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, bitwise operators do that, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators for details.

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format.

Comment: @georg op has "does the operator & perform the conversion to binary?" And I suppose I answered that. 2's complement format implies binary form

Comment: You (and the OP) seem to be confusing "binary notation" for numbers (like `0b1000`) and their internal representation (which is always "binary" on a binary computer).

Answer (score 4):

```
1111101000 // 1000
0000001111 // 0xf
---------- & operator 
0000001000 // 8 in binary system
```

---

The numbers `1000` (`dec`) and `0b1000` (`bin`)  have the same ending in binary representation (`1000`) and the same length as `0xf` (four digits in binary - `1111`)

Therefore you have the same result in both cases for `bitwise` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Because you take 1000 as decimal. According to the documentation for [Numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates), only numbers which starts with zero are treated as binary, octal, hexadecimal or depending as decimal.

```
   f hex = 0000001111 bin
1000 dec = 1111101000 bin
       &   0000001000 bin = 8 dec
```

Comment: so is the 1000 is converted to 32 bit binary as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)?

Comment: @Maximus all data in the computer stored as binary data, even video and music. And `&` just makes binary `AND`(multiplies bitwise) with numbers

Comment: @isvforall, yes, I know that, thank you :). My question was about specifics of type conversion in javascript

Comment: @NinaScholz, ok, thanks. _Because you take 1000 as decimal_ - why do you say decimal?

Comment: @NinaScholz I feel deja vu :)

Comment: 1000 is in javascript a decimal number. for the bitmasking problem, please have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type

Comment: @isvforall, yes, but no pitfall today.

Comment: @Maximus, please see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt, too

Comment: @Maximus I've tried to explain why result is the same in both cases, maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: @NinaScholz, thanks, I see now what you mean by `decimal` - you mean a number with a base of 10, right? Thanks for the links

Comment: @isvforall, yes, I've seen it, it is indeed helpful, thanks!